# MySQL Order year field by closest match

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I'm trying to order some dates so that they are listed in a particular order closest to a specified date:

```
id  year
---------
1   2010
2   2011
3   1992
4   1996
5   1987
6   1988
```

The result should look like (if I specify 1992 as the year to order by):

```
id  year
---------

3   1992
4   1996 <4 away
5   1987 <5 away
6   1988 <6 away
1   2010 <8 away
2   2011 <9 away
```

I want it so that it returns all dates, but the most relevant (closest) first in the list.

Sorry I have revised my question to make it more clear what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What would your result set look like?

Comment: From the question it seems like you would just want `ORDER BY year`.  What about that doesn't work?

Comment: From what I understood you need SELECT * FROM table WHERE year >= '1992' ORDER BY year; But you would not ask a question if it was so easy ;)

Comment: Sorry guys, I've revised my question with an example of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: What is "... # away" supposed to mean to us?  If you have years up to 2025, what do you expect to see?

Comment: If I specify the year 1992 to order by it will return dates which are closest to that year in ascending order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should solve your problem.

```
SELECT *
FROM `table`
ORDER BY ABS(1992-`year`) ASC
```

Comment: Unnecessary, and unlikely to use an index if one existed on (or included) the `year` field because of using the `ABS` function.

Answer (score 4):

Am I missing something? Isn't it just:

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE year >= '1992'
ORDER BY year ASC
```

Then to edit I guess...

```
SELECT *, ABS(year - 1992)
FROM table
ORDER BY ABS(year-1992) ASC
```

I think that will work

Comment: The second example is unnecessary, and unlikely to use an index if one existed on (or included) the `year` field because of using the `ABS` function.